# Error of searching

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

I created a new site in SharePoint Online, when using the default search box it is throwing 404 error:

[image]

Did any one else experienced it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution (don't know the exact reason but my search is working now) in the Site settings-> Search Settings:

You can see there is a Unchecked check box [Use the same result page setting as my parent.]. I just checked it and my search is working now.

[image]